# Google OAuth 2.0 issue with Login with google and to get access token auth/callback in production server Callback URL error 404 Not Found

Tags: google-oauth, google-analytics-api, react-google-login

When I login with google by backend Node.js and frontend React.js for accessing google analytics user data
In localhost:3000 and development server, Login with google, i got response type code from URL and i got access token and refresh token both in auth/callback, everything is 200 status code

but
when I live the website in production server, frontend React.js, and backend Node.js coding everything is the same in development coding and the same config in the AWS server
I try the login with the google, when i got code in browser Network field and the code URL with status code 301 permanently.

and auth/callback/ failed 404 not found and returned with pass code into url .

Everything wroks as per Google GUideline
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow.

Why it throw auth/callback/ 404 not found in production server but auth/callback/ works well in development server

[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViGLh.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbnuO.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHhiQ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKqqn.png)